# SSRS. I need to add "terms and conditions" to the end of a quote

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

SQL Server Reporting Services. I need to add "terms and conditions" to the end of a quote., which is basically simple report, maybe 1-2 pages long. Is there an "End of Report" field/area in SSRS where I can insert this pre-defined text?

Comment: Please consider revising what you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put a textbox at the bottom of the report?

Comment: Put a rectangle or text box in with the "terms and conditions".  And have the visibility set for the last page.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have said you can do this with a visibility expression. The easiest way is to use the Globals!OverallPageNumber field, but this will mean your T&C's will have to be in a footer.

Right click your report and add a page footer then inside the footer add a textbox containing your T&Cs then right click the textbox and select properties and then visibility then show or hide based on an expression and then use this

```
=Globals!OverallPageNumber<>Globals!OverallTotalPages
```

as your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers. This is what I ended up doing:
1) Added a new Tablix to my report, sandwiched between main tablix and footers.
2) Made new tablix page-wide/removed all rows from tablix.
3) Linked the tablix to a dataset containing a query that would never be true: i.e. "select item from dbo.item_master where item='ZZ99ZZ99ZZ99'
4) Merge all columns so I have just one column.
5) Pasted the full T&C text to field 1 of tablix.